# how to fetch multiple database values directly from the database to html?

Tags: javascript, php, database

I am trying to create a sparkline chart where the transaction amount is being fetched from the database .but the problem I am facing is I am not available to retrieve multiple values from the database directly into the html page. here is my htm code for the above .

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     window.onload = function staticFetch(){
        var thisURL = window.location.href;
        var thisSession = new Array();
        thisSession = thisURL.split("?"); //This grabs all URL parameters
        var session = thisSession[1];       
        thisSession = session.split("="); //This gets the session ID from URL
        var session_id = thisSession[1];
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
          {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
          xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
          }
        else
          {// code for IE6, IE5
          xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
          }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
          {
          if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
            {
                result=xmlhttp.responseText;
                thisSession = result.split("&");
                document.getElementById("account_status").innerHTML=thisSession[0];
                document.getElementById("total_amount").innerHTML=thisSession[1];
                document.getElementById("total_transactions").innerHTML=thisSession[2];
                document.getElementById("balance_funds").innerHTML=thisSession[3];
                document.getElementById("avg_amount").innerHTML=thisSession[4];

            }
          }     
        xmlhttp.open("GET","dashboardStaticFetch.php?session_id="+session_id,true);
        xmlhttp.send();     
  }   
</script>

<div class="text-center padder m-b-n-sm m-t-sm">
                                  <div class="sparkline" data-type="line" data-resize="true" data-height="65" data-width="100%" data-line-width="2" data-line-color="#fff" data-spot-color="#fff" data-fill-color="" data-highlight-line-color="#fff" data-spot-radius="3">0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0</div>

                              </div>
```

I am using the JavaScript onload function which fetches the data from the database using php script

Comment: How is this question related to facebook or linked in?

Comment: can you please post the server script also as it is difficult to understand what the server is sending to you. BTW FYI you cant get multiple values in a single ajax request until or unless server is sending you the multiple records by encoding them in the json format or any other thing